# Linux Bash. what is the difference between 2 lines?

Tags: linux, bash, scripting

I have a following bash script:

```
 1  #!/bin/bash
 2  query='query= SELECT * WHERE { ?s ?p ?o } LIMIT 5'
 3  cmd="curl $1 -s -d \"$query\""
 4  echo "$cmd"
 5  # curl $1 -s -d "$query"
 6  # $cmd
```

5th and 6th lines must do the same. When i uncomment the 5th line, everything works fine. But with the 6th line nothing doesn't work.

So i'm wondering whats the difference?

Thanks.

Comment: and what does echo "$cmd" display?

Comment: Have you tried `eval "$cmd"` ?

Comment: echo "$cmd" displays: curl http://localhost:2001/sparql -s -d "query= SELECT * {}"

Comment: with eval everyting works fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Line 5 passes `$query` as a single argument. Line 6 passes each word of `$query` as a separate argument, with `"` at the beginning of the first and `"` at the end of the last. [Put your arguments in an array instead.](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050)

Answer (score 2):

No; in line 4 you are just displaying the command by "echo"ing it; line 6 actually executes the command.

E.g.

```
$eg="ls /var/www"
echo $eg #This would literally return ls /var/www"
$eg #This would return the directory listing of /var/www/ (actually run the command).
```

Comment: I'm certain the OP already understands that. Note that the question asks how lines 5 and 6 are different, not how lines 4 and 6 are different. Line 4 seems to just be debugging.